# How can i find optical flow of a live video stream (Android IPWebcam) in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have written a code which works fine for a recorded video or video from webcam of my laptop.. but i need it to work with video directly from my phone.. Now i have been able to get video from phone and show it through python. But i need frames of this video to apply OpticalFlow function on it. (calcOpticalFlowFarneback).. Here's my two codes. i'll be thankful for your help.

This is code for getting video from android phone's camera to python

```
import cv2
import urllib2
import numpy as np
import sys

host = "192.168.1.2:8080"
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    host = sys.argv[1]

hoststr = 'http://' + host + '/video'
print 'Streaming ' + hoststr

stream=urllib2.urlopen(hoststr)

bytes=''
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow(hoststr,i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

**And this one is relevant portion for motion flow, notice i need frames from video**

```
vid=cv2.VideoCapture('vidaflv.flv')

ret, frame = vid.read()
imgrayp = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


while True:
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if ret:
        imgray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(imgrayp,imgray,None,0.5,3,15,3,5,1.2,0)


    cv2.imshow('Optical flow',draw_flow(frame,flow))
    imgrayp=imgray 
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('e'):
        break
```

what i can't figure out is how to get a frame from live stream video code to put in my optical flow fuction..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Withourt being able to test this, I'd try something like:

```
import cv2
import urllib2
import numpy as np
import sys

host = "192.168.1.2:8080"
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    host = sys.argv[1]

hoststr = 'http://' + host + '/video'
print 'Streaming ' + hoststr

stream=urllib2.urlopen(hoststr)

bytes=''
FirstTime=True
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        if FirstTime=True:
            FirstTime=False
            imgrayp = cv2.cvtColor(i,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        imgray = cv2.cvtColor(i,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(imgrayp,imgray,None,0.5,3,15,3,5,1.2,0)

        cv2.imshow('Optical flow',draw_flow(frame,flow))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

Comment: How did you get the draw_flow part of "cv2.imshow('Optical flow',draw_flow(frame,flow))" to work? What Version of OpenCV and python are you using?